# How to add a class name in every row without effect the rest of the rows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map, class-names

How to add a class name in every row without effect the rest of the rows

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './testEfect.css';

const Test = () => {

    const arrayTest = [
        {
            name: '11',
            id: '11'
        },
        {
            name: '22',
            id: '22'
        },
        {
            name: '33',
            id: '33'
        },
    ]

    const [state, setState] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        const newState = event;

        setState(state ? false : true);

    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {arrayTest.map((x, index) => {
                return (
                    <ul key={index} className={state ? 'deletEfect' : ''}>
                        <li id={x.id} >
                            {x.name}
                            <button onClick={(event) => handleClick(x.id)}>Delete</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “every row without effect the rest of the rows”? How can you effect every row, but not the rest?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `className={\`deletEfect${index}\`}`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-drake-x92sp

Comment: Click on the delete button and you will see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you say the state is false; it is assuming the state is false for the whole component. It doesn't update the row but the whole component. So, at first, you need to add a deleted property that will take a different value for each row.

So,

```
const arrayTest = [
    {
      name: "11",
      id: "11",
      deleted: false
    },
    {
      name: "22",
      id: "22",
      deleted: false
    },
    {
      name: "33",
      id: "33",
      deleted: false
    }
  ];

  const [state, setState] = useState(arrayTest); //initial state
```

Now, when you render, you don't need to use that arrayTest. But you need to use the state. We won't touch arrayTest ever again. So we use,

```
{state.map((x, index) => {
        return (
          <ul key={index} className={x.deleted ? "testEfect" : ""}>
            <li id={x.id}>
              {x.name}
              <button onClick={(event) => handleClick(x.id)}>Delete</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
```

Notice we use `state.map`. We also send `x.id` to `handleClick` function.
Why? Because we will use that id to change the deleted value of the object. So our `handleClick` becomes,

```
const handleClick = (id) => {
    const newState = state.map((element) => {
      if (element.id === id)
        return Object.assign({}, element, {
          deleted: element.deleted ? false : true
        });
      return element;
    });
    setState(newState);
  };
```

This is just updating the state in an immutable way.

Here is the full [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-waterfall-sr6ri?file=/src/App.js) for your convenience.